# Android TextView with style Bold in several words in code

Tags: android, string, textview

I need to put some text(spanString1) in bold in the textview code and I have done this but does not work:

```
 SpannableStringBuilder spanString1 = new SpannableStringBuilder (getString(R.string.HOY));

    spanString1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),0,spanString1.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    valor1.setText("¿Qué 3 cosas puedes hacer de aquí a " + spanString2 + " para " + Valor1 + "?");
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with HTML

```
String boldone = "your bold text"   //get your string here
String valor1 = "<b>" + boldone + "</b> " + othertext; 
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(valor1));
```